# Can't resolve '@react/dialog' in Login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use `react-dialog`.

To install I did `npm install react-dialog --legacy-peer-deps`

When I run the application I'm getting the following error.

**Error**

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@react/dialog' in '/Users/elizafury/book-main/src/components/auth'
ERROR in ./src/components/auth/Login.js 8:0-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@react/dialog' in '/Users/elizafury/book-main/src/components/auth'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

**I've tried**

- installing and using yarn
- updated npm
- removed node_modules and package-lock.json and then reinstalled npm
- Import Dialog from "react-dialog" which results in this error:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/efury1/book-main/node_modules/react-dialog/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (49:7):
      47 |
      48 |     return (
    > 49 |       <div ref="modal" className={classes}>
         |       ^
      50 |         <div className="dialog-title">{this.props.title}</div>
      51 |         <section ref="dialogContent" className="dialog-content">{this.props.message}</section>
      52 |         <div className="dialog-action"{this.props.action}></div>

    Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
    If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dialog/index.js
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
```

I'm still quite new to Javascript and I'm wondering how I should proceed to get dialog-react working?

**My Code**

I've done `import {Dialog} from '@react/dialog'` because I was following a video from the EpicReactCourse.

Here is the code I'm using react-dialog for:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// eslint-disable-next-line
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Logo} from '../Logo'
import {Dialog} from '@react/dialog'

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="home">Welcome to bookie</h1>
      <Logo width="100" height="100"/>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => alert('login clicked')}>Login</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => alert('login clicked')}> Register</button>
      </div>
      <Dialog aria-label="Login form" isOpen={true}> //using Dialog
        <div>
          <button>Close</button>
        </div>
        <h3>Login</h3>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

**Package.Json**

```js
{
  "name": "books",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "dialog-react": "^1.1.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dialog": "^0.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should take another look at [the documentation](https://github.com/mohitgupta8888/react-dialog#usage). It should be `import Dialog from "react-dialog"`

Comment: Hi Phil, I've tried `Import Dialog from "react-dialog"` and I'm now getting a webpack error `ERROR in ./node_modules.react-dialog/index.js `  `Module build failed` . I will relook at the documentation though :)

Comment: Then I suggest you [report an issue](https://github.com/mohitgupta8888/react-dialog/issues/new). Try to provide more information than you have here though, in particular the actual error message in full

Comment: Perfect, I'll do that right away! Thank you, Phil!

Comment: I was sort of dropping a hint that you should also [edit] your question to provide more detail

Comment: can u share the package.json file here

Comment: Thank you, Phil. I've just tried to add more detail to my question! Let me know if the detail is still lacking.

Comment: Also, I've just added the package.json in my question :)